# How can I make Files search recursively within a network share?

Tags: nautilus, search, shared-folders

When I use Files to search within a network share, it says:

> Remote location - only searching the current folder

[image: Remote location - only searching the current folder]

How can I make it search all folders like it normally does? I understand that searching a remote location will take longer, and I still want to do it.

Comment: Have you tried with find command via terminal?

Comment: Yep, successfully searching using a command-line utility demonstrated that a recursive search of this network share is possible and that I was using the correct search terms. It didn't do anything to address the behavior of Files, though.

Comment: I didn't get the last part , address behaviour of files.. whats that supposed to mean . Please elaborate

Comment: It was a useful workaround but didn't answer the question.

Comment: rɑːdʒɑ - OP mentioned Files (the app) not files the objects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In newer versions of Ubuntu (in my case 18.04) you can open from *Files* > *Preferences* > *Search & Preview* tab, and check "All locations" under "Search in subfolders".

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you also struggle to find the menu bar. Look at the top left corner. There is an arrow down to open the menu (next to Activities). If you have multiple monitors, check all top left corners, because the menu bar might be nowhere near the application window, and seems to be "missing".

Answer (score 8):

You can change the Nautilus preferences via **dconf-tools**, `/org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/recursive-search`, change the value to 'always'.

[image: screenshot]

Or on a terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences recursive-search 'always'
```

Comment: on centos 7 I had to first run `sudo yum install dconf-editor` then I was able to use `dconf-editor` to set the above-mentioned setting

Comment: In this particular case, you can do this with dconf. `dconf write /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/recursive-search "'always'"`. I prefer this to installing `dconf-editor` for a one-off modification. The downside is you need to know the valid key values. You can discover the valid values by running `gsettings range org.gnome.nautilus.preferences recursive-search`

Answer (score 0):

**In Ubuntu 22.04:**
Files > Preferences > **Performances** section: Set "Search in Subfolders" to "All locations".